# Thomson scattering at high frequencies

Tags: electromagnetism, scattering

When studying the scattering of a monochromatic plane E&M wave by a point charge and after finding the differential cross section of the process I read a sentence saying **"This result is valid only at low frequencies, that is when the momentum of the incident photon can be ignored."** I wonder what happens when we don't make this assumption. That is to say what happens in this scattering process at high frequencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compton scattering! The scattering becomes inelastic, such that the photon gives up some of its energy to the electron.

NB An electron cannot absorb a photon because such a reaction cannot simultaneously conserve energy and momentum.